# Android No such table code 1 SQLITE_ERROR

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm struggling on an sql query I have:

```
"SELECT A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " + 
"FROM TABLE_QUANTITY JOIN TABLE_INGREDIENT ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name"
```

This is telling me:

> no such table: TABLE_QUANTITY (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

The tables are:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUANTITY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_QUANTITY + "(" + COL_ID +
     " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT," + COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY + " NUMERIC, " +
     COL_RECIPE + " TEXT," + COL_INGREDIENT + " TEXT, FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_RECIPE + ") " +
     "REFERENCES " + TABLE_RECIPE + "(" + COL_RECIPE_NAME + "), FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_INGREDIENT + ") " +
     "REFERENCES " + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "(" + COL_INGREDIENT_NAME + "))";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_INGREDIENTS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_INGREDIENTS + "("
     + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT," + COL_INGREDIENT_NAME + " TEXT,"
     + COL_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," + COL_MEASUREMENT + " TEXT," + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + " TEXT, " +
     "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_MEASUREMENT + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_MEASUREMENT + "(" + COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME + "), " +
     "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_INGREDIENT_TYPE + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_INGREDIENT_TYPE + "(" + COL_TYPE_NAME + "))";
```

**Update**

```
public void loadRecipe() {
    itemRecipe.clear();
    db = (new DatabaseManager(this).getWritableDatabase());
    String RECIPE_SEARCH = " SELECT + A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
            "FROM " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY + " AS A JOIN " + DatabaseManager.TABLE_INGREDIENTS +
            " AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name";
    String selectQuery = "";
    selectQuery = selectQuery + RECIPE_SEARCH;

    c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{"%" + search_name + "%"});
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RecipeList recipeList = new RecipeList();
            recipeList.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COL_ID")));
            recipeList.setIngredient_amount(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_QUANTITY")));
            recipeList.setMeasurement_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_MEASUREMENT_NAME")));
            recipeList.setIngredient_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_INGREDIENT_NAME")));
            recipeList.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COL_DESCRIPTION")));
            itemRecipe.add(recipeList);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }

}
```

Made some chnages based on suggestions, thankyou. However still getting
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: QUANTITY (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT + A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description FROM QUANTITY AS A JOIN INGREDIENTS AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name

Comment: Remove `+` from `SELECT + A.ingredient_quantity`. The error is: `no such table: QUANTITY`. So the table `QUANTITY` was not created. Uninstall the app from the device, recheck the onCreate() method of SQLiteOpenHelper so that it contains for both tables correct CREATE statements and rerun. If this does not work try with a clean device.

Comment: Thanks. That solved that problem, but this is one after another now I get     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stu54259.plan2cook/com.stu54259.plan2cook.Recipe}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.

Comment: Ask a new question where you provide all the relevant code, errors and info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TABLE_QUANTITY` and `TABLE_INGREDIENT` are string variables that you must concatenate inside the SQL statement and set the aliases A and B also:

```
"SELECT A.ingredient_quantity, B.measurement_name, B.ingredient_name, B.description " +
"FROM " + TABLE_QUANTITY + "AS A JOIN " + TABLE_INGREDIENT + 
" AS B ON A.ingredient = B.ingredient_name"
```

What is also wrong is this:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT
```

in both `CREATE` statements of the 2 tables.
Remove the comma so it is:

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

You may have to uninstall the app from the device so the db is deleted and rerun to recreate the db and the tables.

Comment: Thanks. This is SQlite in Android studio it insists upon a comma before AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: @RevansArden check this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=aa145f4ea0c74b18bca903704af66753 to understand what you are doing wrong. The correct syntax is `...INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ...` and it works also in Android Studio.

Comment: Also  getting cannot find symbol error as the TABLE_QUANTITY and TABLE_INGREDIENTS are located in the DatabaseManager class not the Recipe class. How do I get round this? Any help would be great.

Comment: You must use `DatabaseManager.TABLE_QUANTITY`.

Comment: Tried that and it tells me about private access.

Comment: ', <column constraint>, ASC, AUTOINCREMENT, DESC, ON or comma expected, got 'AUTO'

Comment: I don't have your full code. This is an answer about the problem as you described it in your question.